# Почему не работает функция по проверке последовательности

Tags: javascript

Есть Задача:
Написать функцию, которая на входе принимает массив из целых чисел и определяет возможно ли получить ряд чисел, выстроенных по возрастанию, удалив из данного массива максимум один элемент (без дополнительной сортировки).

*Пример:*

- Для числового ряда `[1, 3, 2, 1]`, функция вернет `false`, поскольку в данном случае при удалении любого числа, оставшиеся числа не будут расположены по возрастанию
- Для числового ряда `[1, 3, 2]`, функция вернет `true`, поскольку в данном случае при удалении `3` или `2`, оставшиеся числа будут расположены по возрастанию: `[1,2]` или `[1,3]` соответственно.

Вот примерное решение

```
function a(arr) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        arr.splice(i, 1); 
        if (compare(arr)) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 

    function compare(array) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) { 
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 

    return false; 
}
```

Но при массиве, скажем [1, 1, 1] возвращает true или при других явно не правильных последовательностях тоже true
Здесь false, хотя должно быть true [3, 6, 8, 1]

подаскажите, где может быть ошибка
Спасибо

Comment: потому что **не стоит** использовать _splice_ внутри цикла. Обрати внимание, что ты сам массив переданный в функцию ломаешь. Splice вообще стоит очень осторожно использовать

Comment: Лучше бы Вы не "примерное решение" показали, а расписали алгоритм, который намерены использовать при решении.

Comment: @Akina, скорее всего самое простое: убирать по очереди элемент из массива, и проверять - удовлетворяет ли получившийся массив условиям

Comment: @Grundy да вижу... просто очень хотелось спросить у автора, из какого массива он, по его мнению, будет удалять один элемент при втором удалении...

Comment: @Akina, ну, чтобы это знать, надо знать, что splice меняет массив к которому применяется